Is this expect behavior for NumPy indexing? If so, why?
I am using NumPy version 2.1.3 and Python 3.12.2. Say I define
ones_arr = np.ones((1, 2, 3))

Now I slice
ones_arr[0, :, [0, 1, 2]]

The result has shape (3, 2), but I would expect it to have shape (2, 3). Indeed, both
ones_arr[0, :, :][:, [0, 1, 2]]

and
ones_arr[:, :, [0, 1, 2]][0, :, :]

give what I would expect. Is this expected behavior, and if so, why?

This an example of mixed advanced and basic indexing.  It is documented, and has been asked a number of times.  Hopefully my duplicate explains the 'why' well enough. :-)

@hpaulj Yes, this answers my question beautifully. Thanks!
